# How to get row id with Dojo dataGrid

Tags: dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I'm using dojo dataGrid, and i need to get the row id.
When i use the "rowIndex" event, i get the "id" of the row, but, if i sort the grid, the data keeps another value in the row "id".

Can someone tell me how to solve this problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the row of the grid when selected?   Why do you need the row id?   Usually I find if I let dojo handle row and data sorting for me and just pull in the selected item when I need it I'm better off.

e.g.

```
  function onSelectedGridParm(nRow){
    var objGridParm = dijit.byId("gridParm");
    var item = objGridParm.getItem(nRow);
    // single select - use an array here for multi select
    //   and remove in onDeselect 
    _selectedVariable = item;
    fnEnableButton( "VariableEdit" );
    fnEnableButton( "VariableDelete" );
  }

  ....

  <div id="gridParm" dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid"
       style="width: 100%; height: 550px;"
       structure="layoutVariables"
       selectionMode="single"
       noDataMessage="No Data Found with current filters"
       onSelected="onSelectedGridParm"
       onDeselected="onDeselectedGridParm"
       rowsPerPage="50"
       >
  </div>
```